# How to get an idToken that is valid for development from firebase without having to spin up my frontend?

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I am working on some firebase functions. This one will check if an user is logged in in firebase first. However this is a bit of a hassle in development. Now I need to login on the frontend first to get the `id_token`, pass it to my function url, then see the result.

The process I am following is described in the official docs: https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/verify-id-tokens

**node.js**

```
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
admin.initializeApp();

module.exports = function( request, response ) {
  if( !request.query.id_token )
    response.status(400).json({message: 'id token has not been provided'});

  admin.auth()
  .verifyIdToken( request.query.id_token )
  .then( token => {
    // TODO: redirect to payment portal
    return response.status(200).json({message: 'Success'});
  })
  .catch( error => {
    return response.status(401).json({message: 'You are currently not logged in as an authorised user'});
  })

}
```

Is there a way to get an `id_token` that is valid from firebase without having to spin up my frontend? Good and simple alternatives solutions are welcome too.

NOTE: I am using the firebase emulators during development.

Comment: did you find a way for this? I had a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66205191/how-to-authenticate-firebase-cloud-functions-in-functions-emulator-using-the-use/66222710?noredirect=1#comment117246477_66222710)

Answer (score 3):

Since you're using the Firebase emulators you may create a fake user and retrieve an id token programmatically. The code below creates and logs in a user and returns an id_token that will be accepted by your function.

```js
var firebase = require("firebase/app");
require("firebase/auth");

// Initialize Firebase and connect to the Authentication emulator
var firebaseConfig = {
    // Insert Firebase config here
};
firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
firebase.auth().useEmulator('http://localhost:9099/');

// Create a fake user and get the token
firebase.auth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword("example@example.com", "password")
    .then((userCredential) => {
        console.log("User created")
    });

firebase.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword("example@example.com", "password")
    .then((userCredential) => {
        console.log("User logged in")
        userCredential.user.getIdToken().then((idToken) => {
            console.log(idToken)
        });
    });
```