# Get unsigned token for user from firebase auth emulator without frontend

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication, nestjs, firebase-admin

I am writing a custom backend (nestjs) in which I want to verify if the token from firebase auth is valid and retrieve user information too.

I do not want to use the actual firebase auth so I ended up using firebase local emulator.

Now I want to test my endpoint written in nestjs using postman wherein I send the unsigned token from postman for nestjs to verify from local emulator. But I couldn't find a way to create an unsigned token without creating a UI for the same, I really do not want to spend time in creating a react application to just `console.log` a token. Is there any better way to do this that I might be missing ??

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Assuming your Authentication emulator runs on port `9099` and you have a user created, you should be able to make the following HTTP `POST` request to get a token. The token is in the `idToken` field of the response object.

`http://localhost:9099/identitytoolkit.googleapis.com/v1/accounts:signInWithPassword?key=any_key_you_want`

Body (JSON):

```
{
  "email": "your-user@mail.com",
  "password": "some-password"   
}
```

Response:

```
{
    "kind": "identitytoolkit#VerifyPasswordResponse",
    "registered": true,
    "localId": "yourUserId",
    "email": "your-user@mail.com",
    "idToken": "someIdToken",
    "refreshToken": "someRefreshToken",
    "expiresIn": "3600"
}
```

I found this solution playing with a React application with the `firebase` (^9.6.2) package installed, setting `connectAuthEmulator(auth, "http://localhost:9099");`, and looking at the request it made when I logged in.